# Numpy 1d Array CumSquare of the values

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, multidimensional-array, cumsum

I am looking to emulate the functionality of `numpy.cumsum()`, except I need to capture the cumulative squares of the values.

For example: I have an array that is [1,2,3,4].

I can use `numpy.cumsum(array)` to return an `array([1,3,6,10])`.  My goal is to use some fast numpy trick to get the cumulative squares of the values.

In pure Python using a list:

```
>>> y = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sqVal = 0
>>> for val in y:
...     sqVal += val*val
...     print sqVal
... 
1
5
14
30
```

I tried `numpy.cumprod()`, but that is cumulative product, not the sum of the cumulative squares of the values.  My desire to use NumPy is purely based on speed.  Using `cumsum()` is substantially faster than using for loops (which makes sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy's `square` function in addition to `cumsum`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [3]: np.square(a)
Out[3]: array([ 1,  4,  9, 16])

In [4]: np.cumsum(np.square(a))
Out[4]: array([ 1,  5, 14, 30])
```